# Receiving a Connection Refusal in Zeppelin

Tags: apache, docker, apache-zeppelin

I'm receiving a connection refusal (see bottom) when attempting to run paragraphs in Zeppelin. I installed Docker Toolbox on my Windows machine, and then ran the following container in the Docker Terminal:

```
docker run -it --privileged=true -m 4096m -p 2222:22 -p 8888:8888 -p 8889:8889 -h bootcamp1.docker sunlab/bigdata:0.04.1 /bin/bash
```

After running this, I started the following services:

```
sudo service zeppelin start
sudo service sshd start
sudo service zookeeper-server start
sudo service hadoop-yarn-proxyserver start
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-namenode start
sudo service hadoop-hdfs-datanode start
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
sudo service hadoop-mapreduce-historyserver start
sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
sudo service spark-worker start
sudo service spark-master start
sudo service hbase-regionserver start
sudo service hbase-master start
sudo service hbase-thrift start
```

Once these were running, I successfully connected to my Zeppelin Notebook where I am noticing this error. Something peculiar that I noticed is that if I start Zeppelin last, the service actually fails to start. I am wondering if the issue is related to this phenomenon. Does anyone know how to resolve this error?

The tutorial I am trying to follow can be found at the below link (for reproducibility):

http://www.sunlab.org/teaching/cse8803/fall2016/lab/env-docker/

Error:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200) at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182) at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392) at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579) at org.apache.thrift.transport.TSocket.open(TSocket.java:182) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:51) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.ClientFactory.create(ClientFactory.java:37) at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:60) at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:861) at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:435) at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:363) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreterProcess.getClient(RemoteInterpreterProcess.java:139) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.init(RemoteInterpreter.java:129) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.remote.RemoteInterpreter.getFormType(RemoteInterpreter.java:257) at org.apache.zeppelin.interpreter.LazyOpenInterpreter.getFormType(LazyOpenInterpreter.java:104) at org.apache.zeppelin.notebook.Paragraph.jobRun(Paragraph.java:198) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.Job.run(Job.java:169) at org.apache.zeppelin.scheduler.RemoteScheduler$JobRunner.run(RemoteScheduler.java:322) at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471) at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178) at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:292) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```